# Providing network drive access to a windows service

Tags: windows, shell-scripting, service, startup-scripts

I have a windows service, which requires access to a network drive.
As Windows Service does not perform interactive logon, it's not possible to use mapped drive from active directory user logon script.
Which would be the best - secure and elegant way to provide a network drive for such a windows service? A helper script? Or, is there any other solution?

/Windows 2008

Update:
Unfortunately, this services does not allow to use UNC path, otherwise we would gladly use our domain shares.

Access to a network share is our requirement. Service is able to use shares mapped to a letters. It's not the most elegant way, though.

Comment: The service can't use a UNC path? (Why?)

Comment: Don't know why. It does not accept UNCs.

Comment: What account is the service running under?

Comment: The service requires access to a network drive but doesn't support UNC paths? Well then you're out of luck. How is it that the service was built with a dependency that it doesn't support? Talk about a catch-22...

Comment: This service somehow tests by itselfs validity of path. That's the problem. Just to clarify. This service does not require explicit access to a network share. By default it supports only letter drives (including these mapped to a letters). But we want to use a network share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As drive letters are ephemeral, it would be best to use UNC paths instead of drive letters. If the service is unable to handle UNC paths, consider creating a symlink to the destination like

```
mklink c:\remotenetdir \\server\remote\netdir
```

and use the local path (`c:\remotenetdir`) in the service configuration.

Obviously, the service account would need to have the permission to access `\\server\remote\netdir` for this to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this services does not allow to use UNC path, otherwise we would gladly use our domain shares.

Comment: Making a link is a good idea.